# Environment Variable with yesterday's date

Tags: linux, bash

I'd like to set an environment variable on an Ubuntu machine.  The variable would be equal to yesterday's date in the format yymmdd.

```
export YESTERDAYS_DATE=get date, format date
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `export YESTERDAYS_DATE=$(date --date yesterday "+%y%m%d")`

Comment: Thanks for solving in a minute what was going to take me an hour, really appreciated.

Comment: We normally use something like this for all our scripts:  TIMESTAMP=$( date +"%A - %B %d, %Y - %T.%N" ), just add the --date thing to it, but anubhava got it right...